# Backbone.js pass array to view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to pass an array to a view like this

```
this.account_nav = new AccountNav.View({
   views: [
     { ref: new Member.Views.AccountNav({ model: this.model }), id: 'viewA' }, 
     { ref: new Member.Views.SettingsNav({ model: this.model}), id: 'viewB' }
   ]
});
```

However there is an error:

> Uncaught Error: The argument associated with selector '' is defined
>   and a View.  Set `manage` property to true for Backbone.View
>   instances. backbone.layoutmanager.js:208

pointing to

```
this.account_nav = new AccountNav.View({
```

Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: Have you tried to set manage property to true for Backbone.View ?

Comment: Yes it set to true by default in my project.

Comment: and what's going on here -> backbone.layoutmanager.js:208 when you debug it ?

Answer (score 0):

If your View definition is created using `Backbone.Layout.extend` rather than `Backbone.View.extend`, this issue shouldn't arise.

To cite the Layout Manager documentation example:

```
var LoginView = Backbone.Layout.extend({
  template: "#login-template"
});
```

*versus*

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // [...]
});
```

https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Example-usage#structuring-a-view